# Can I limit the search on sub items based on other fields of subitems

Tags: elasticsearch

Hello guys I'm new in elastic and here comes the doubt.

When querying a json index, I need to find in an array of complex objects a string only in some array items.

In example:

considering the following info I need to query a text value on "partes.Nome" field,  only in items with 78 value in field partes.IdTipoParticipacao and with the values 44 and 1 on IdAreaAtuacao field.

My problem is that when i query for a text contained on partes.IdTipoParticipacao with the value 14 it still returns me a value.

Can I limit the search on sub items based on other fields of subitems?

### If I search "Benício Lucca Caleb Alves" it still return though partes.IdTipoParticipacao equals 14  .

Document Example:

```html
POST indicedocs/_doc/17C9CA74-1E3D-4A63-A7B3-FA8FD3FF70BF
{
  "Id" : "17C9CA74-1E3D-4A63-A7B3-FA8FD3FF70BF",
  "NivelSigilo" : 0,
  "Numero" : "040700000052022",
  "IdAreaAtuacao" : 7,
  "NumeroFormatado" : "0407.0000005/2022",
  "partes" : [
    {
      "IdTipoParticipacao" : 14,
      "TipoParte" : 0,
      "Participacao" : "Interessado",
      "Policial" : "Não",
      "CPF" : "23315018154",
      "CPFFormatado" : "233.150.181-54",
      "Nome" : "Benício Lucca Caleb Alves",
      "Nacionalidade" : "Brasileira"
    },
    {
      "IdTipoParticipacao" : 78,
      "TipoParte" : 0,
      "Nome" : "Emilly e Diogo Financeira Ltda",
      "CNPJ" : "72217026000105",
      "CNPJFormatado" : "72.217.026/0001-05"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Query example:

```html
GET indicedocs/_search
{
  "size":1001,
  "query": {
    
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms":{
             "partes.IdTipoParticipacao":[
                78
             ]
          }
        },
        {
           "query_string":{
              "query":"\"Benício Lucca Caleb Alves\"",
              "fields":[
                 "partes.Nome"
              ]
           }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "terms":{
             "IdAreaAtuacao":[
                44,
                1
             ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default elasticsearch just smooshes all the values in all the fields of the array together so there it doesn't know that `14` is related to `Benício Lucca Caleb Alves` and `78` is related to `Emilly e Diogo Financeira Ltda`. By default, field `IdTipoParticipacao` has both values and `Nome` has both values.

To make elastic keep the relationships you need to define `parties` as `nested` and use special `nested` query like this:

```
DELETE test
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "partes": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_doc/17C9CA74-1E3D-4A63-A7B3-FA8FD3FF70BF?refresh
{
  "Id" : "17C9CA74-1E3D-4A63-A7B3-FA8FD3FF70BF",
  "NivelSigilo" : 0,
  "Numero" : "040700000052022",
  "IdAreaAtuacao" : 7,
  "NumeroFormatado" : "0407.0000005/2022",
  "partes" : [
    {
      "IdTipoParticipacao" : 14,
      "TipoParte" : 0,
      "Participacao" : "Interessado",
      "Policial" : "Não",
      "CPF" : "23315018154",
      "CPFFormatado" : "233.150.181-54",
      "Nome" : "Benício Lucca Caleb Alves",
      "Nacionalidade" : "Brasileira"
    },
    {
      "IdTipoParticipacao" : 78,
      "TipoParte" : 0,
      "Nome" : "Emilly e Diogo Financeira Ltda",
      "CNPJ" : "72217026000105",
      "CNPJFormatado" : "72.217.026/0001-05"
    }
  ]
} 

GET test/_search
{
  "size": 1001,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "partes",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "partes.IdTipoParticipacao": [
                  78
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "\"Benício Lucca Caleb Alves\"",
                "fields": [
                  "partes.Nome"
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "IdAreaAtuacao": [
                  44,
                  1
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See [elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) for more information.